# How do I get a ViewController from a UITabBarController programmatically?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In one of my `UIViewControllers` in my `UITabBarController`, I do this:

```
MyTabBarController *myTBC = (MyTabBarController*)self.parentViewController;
for(UIViewController *anyVC in myTBC) {
    if([anyVC.class isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]])
        sVC = (SecondViewController *)anyVC;
    sVC.userLocation = userLocation;
}
```

but I get a warning at the for...line saying:

> Collection expression type MyTabBarController may not respond to countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count.

`MyTabBarController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
for(UIViewController *anyVC in myTBC) {
```

should be:

```
for(UIViewController *anyVC in myTBC.viewControllers) {
```